# What happened in the post-credit scene of "Doctor Strange" (2016)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016

Needless to say, spoilers follow.

In the second post-credits scene,

> Mordo confronts Pangborn.

The two fight, and

> Mordo overpowers his opponent, also extracting some sort of magical essence from Pangborn.

Like this:

[image: Mordo extracting an essence-like glowing orange thingy from Pangborn abdomen]

After this 'procedure'

> Pangborn is left paralysed - like he was before he started learning magic. Mordo says the problem with this world is that there are **"too many sorcerers"**.

How did he do that? Or rather, **what did he do?** I thought the magic was learned, and not intrinsic in everyone.

Does this have any precedent in related comics? Is this a power the comic Mordo is particularly known for?

Comment: I'm voting to close according to our policy on [Future works](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/21267). Unless you can specify that you want answers from existing sources, otherwise at the moment all we can say is "wait till the next movie comes out".

Comment: @Mooz That is *not* what Future Work policy means. He is asking about what happened in an *existing* work, not asking for us to speculate about events/casting/plot in a work that's not out yet. "I don't know the answer based on what I saw" does not a Future Works Close Reason make. There's no reason to specify "from existing sources" because the assumption is never "from non-existing sources".

Comment: @Mooz thanks for pointing that out, I've tried to clarify the question a bit.

Comment: @CreationEdge Thanks for standing up for me :D I've made some corrections, and I think the question should be okay now.

Comment: @Creation the question was asking about the post credits scene which is a prelude of "what's to come", coupled with the fact that the act in question was not seen anywhere in the movie, I'd say they want us to "wait till it comes out", hence Future Works. In my haste to explain my VTC, I remarked "existing sources" by which I meant information we have at hand.

Comment: @Gallifreyan Good edits, that was my intended message. Sorry if I sounded rude.

Comment: @Mooz not at all, thanks for vigilantly protecting our den from off-topicness :D

Comment: Good lord, civil discourse when two people disagree on a point and then come to a mutually agreeable solution? What IS this board coming to?

Comment: "He channels dimensional energy directly into his own body." "He uses magic to walk." What you see him doing is pulling out the energy that Pangborn has been channeling into himself. Presumably, Mordo somehow *also* blocks him from doing it further. Or he just ends up killing him. Unclear at the moment.

Comment: @phantom42 that's what I thought. I was hoping there would be an explanation in comics or otherwise, because "pulling energy out of people" and "people _learning_ to do magic_ are two incompatible things, IMO.

Comment: Why are they incompatible? Mordo learned to do magic *and* to pull energy out of people. The whole movie is about people learning to do magic.

Comment: @phantom42 I mean in this universe, magic is _knowledge_. How did he pull out knowledge? Otherwise, there must be some _midichlorians_ that connect people to magic, and that must be what Mordo pulled out.

Comment: Gallifreyan we know magic isn't just knowledge in the movie, because the Ancient One and main baddie were getting boosted from outside sources. And also, objects can't have intrinsic knowledge (see stone, cape, boots, etc).

Comment: @CreationEdge good point about objects. I'm still not convinced about people though - I thought the implication was that anyone can start to learn magic (i.e. there are no prerequisites, like magical blood). I just can't see how someone can be cut out from magic.

Comment: Precedent: The beginning of the movie, The Ancient One summons her weapons with ease. Later, Strange summons the same weapons, but struggles to keep his weapons active when hit with opposing magic. Pangborn was​ hit by some kind of magic he couldn't defend from. Without a Sling Ring, Pangborn is stuck in his paralysis.

Comment: What is [tag:mcu]?

Comment: @MolagBal Abbreviation for "Marvel cinematic universe" :D I thought it'd be easier to type.

Comment: So you're planning to make [mcu] and [dceu] synonyms of the longer versions?

Comment: @MolagBal Why would I do that?

Comment: I meant [mcu] -> [marvel-cinematic-universe] and similarly for [dceu].

Comment: @MolagBal Yes, that was my intention.

Comment: Oh right, I see the proposed synonyms now. I don't have the tag rep to vote on them.

Answer (score 2):

**Note that these are just speculations, we don't really know what is happening - we will find out later.**

As we learn in the movie, Pangborn

> **channels** dimensional energy directly into his own body.

to bypass the paralysis.

We know for sure:

1. There is some kind of magic energy stolen from Pangborn.
2. Pangborn is left paralyzed, shaking on the floor.
3. Pangborn is a very weak sorcerer and disinterested in broadening his knowledge.

We can speculate that:

- Channeling the energy to compensate whole body paralysis is very hard - Stephen couldn't do it.
- Spells are very hard to cast but are easy to support - see the characters struggle when they begin to cast the spell and how easy they wield magical weapons when fighting.

So, the scene goes as following:

1. Pangborn tries to hit Mordo.
2. Mordo counters and draws the energy that is channeled through him.
3. Pangborn's spell fades away, we can see the progress of his paralysis.
4. Pangborn cannot re-cast this spell since he is too occupied with Mordo (on the basis of previous speculations.)
5. Mordo now has enough time to talk with him.
6. If Mordo won't kill Pangborn we can see his basketball career develop in next movies.

Comment: I understood it so that he erased pangborns ability to cast any spells and do magic completely with whatever he did. you are of a different opinion there?a

Comment: @Thomas yes, to me it looks like he just interrupted his spell and Pangborn just couldn't concentrate/gather whatever was necessary to re-cast his anti-paralysis spell (see point 4). I think it would be possible that someone *else* cast anti-paralysis on Pangborn (long time ago) and Mordo just dispelled his spell, but the characters say it's Pangborn's own magic.

Comment: not so sure....according to wikipedia: "Mordo confronts Pangborn and takes away the energy he uses to walk, stating that Earth has "too many sorcerers"." that would be how I interpreted the scene too. guess that is something to see.

Comment: @Thomas and the whole Wikipedia's section about plot has absolutely no references. I know the movie is a reference, but until they have something stronger than the movie - we'r left with just 'my opinion is that...', as I have stated in the first sentence of my answer.